# Regex : Find a number between space

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract a zip code of six numbers starting with the number `4` from a string. Right now I am using `[4][0-9]{5}`, but it is also matching starting from other numbers, like `020-25468811` and it's returning `468811`. I don't want it to search in the middle of a number, only full numbers.

Comment: Surround your existing regex with `\b`.

Comment: Thanks like this \b[4][0-9]{5}\b

Comment: No Ohaal its not working

Comment: I'm not the one who provided you the answer. In any case, @Jon's regex "works" for the specifications you gave. If it doesn't "work", your specifications are wrong. Elaborate the question and/or provide more/better examples.

Comment: Can you give an example of the string you are trying to extract from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following:

```
(?<!\d)4\d{5}(?!\d)
```

I.e. find 6-digit number starting with 4 and not preceded or followed by digit.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately JS doesn't support lookbehind. In such case need to use capturing group $1 from the following regex
(?:[^\d]|^)(4\d{5})(?!\d)

Answer (score 1):

Your expression right now tries to match any six numbers consisting of a 4 with five numbers between 0 and 9. To fix this behavior you should add word boundaries as per Jon's suggestion.

```
\b[4][0-9]{5}\b
```

More on word boundaries here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a space to the beginning of your regular expression `" 4[0-9]{5}"`. If you need a more universal way of finding the beginning of the number (could it maybe be also be tabulator, a newline, etc?) you should have look at the *predefined character class* `\s`. Also have a look at *boundary matchers*. I dont know which language you are using, but regex work very similar in most languages. Check this [Java regex documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef).

Answer (score -1):

There is a start of line character in regex: ^

You could do:

```
^4[0-9]{5}
```

If the numbers are not always in the beginning of a line, you can more generally use:

```
\<4[0-9]{5}\>
```

To match only whole words.
Both examples work with egrep.